# Number of SQL execution in Oracle 10g database

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to identify the number of sql running parallel in Oracle 10g database?

What would be the maximum number of SQL run in Oracle at a time?

This is really needed to identify the performance of database response time. There is a use case wherein nearly 1 million sql need to be fired and amount of data in the table also few billions.

Really much appreciated your help in this.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but V$session shows all the current sessions in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the response @OldProgrammer, see I'm making 1000 session (between oracle client - server). each session running a 1000 sql concurrently. will Oracle support this?

Comment: You can use commercial and open source benchmark tools. https://www.quest.com/products/benchmark-factory/ http://www.softwaretestingmagazine.com/tools/open-source-database-testing-tools/

Comment: @SriramM - A session can only run one SQL statement at a time.  I would be very, very suspicious of a requirement to run 1 million SQL statements truly simultaneously.  There is no way that any program anywhere can do that without serializing the queries unless you happen to have access to a machine with several hundred thousand processors.  In the vast majority of cases, you would really want to run radically, radically fewer statements that were each doing DML on a large number of rows.

Comment: @JustinCave - Thank you for your broader view on this. Just reinvestigating on this requirement to reduce the volume of SQL statements to run.